# Can we change the image of link (Which is posted by android app) on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Can we change the image of link (Which is posted by android app) on facebook

I am posting some link on FaceBook through my application, but I want other image to be shown on Facebook wall

my code goes like this

```
Intent shareCaptionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareCaptionIntent.setType("image/png");
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "<URL>");
//set caption
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "example caption");
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "example caption");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareCaptionIntent,getString(R.string.share)));
```

I can see Caption and description also.
How can I change the image and make description and caption visible, Please find attached image [image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are just doing a share, the link that you are sharing gets linted (parsed) by Facebook and grabs the meta tags defined on the destination url that you are sharing.

Specific to your question:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A great movie with Sean Connery and Nicolas Cage" />
```

If you have access to change those meta tags, then you can control the image, the title and the description of the post that is displayed on Facebook.

For reference, see http://ogp.me/ as well as using the Facebook debugger http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to lint (parse) the url that you are sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using Android Facebook SDK (change all the stuff that is posted), if you really need it.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

or

PublishFeedHowTo sample demo (L:150-L:154)
https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos/blob/master/PublishFeedHowTo/src/com/facebook/samples/publishfeedhowto/MainFragment.java

Answer (score 1):

No you can change the link of an image you posted on facebook. Facebook it self generates this link when it store the data in there database.

Answer (score 1):

```
        **Using this code you can share any image from your drawable folder** 





     public void share()
      {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception   exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                if(!session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions"))
                        {
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(Aboutcampaign.this, PERMISSIONS));
                        }
                else
                {
                final String message="YOUR STRING MESSAGE";
              // make request to the /me API
                 /* Request request = Request
                          .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Request.Callback() {
                              @Override
                              public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                  showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                              }
                          });
                  request.executeAsync();*/

                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Aboutcampaign.this.getResources(), R.drawable.product_btn);
                // Bitmap BckGrnd = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
                 Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
                     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                         showPublishResult("Shared on Facebook", response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());

                     }
                 });
                 Bundle params = request.getParameters();
              // Add the parameters you want, the caption in this case
              params.putString("name", message);
              // Update the request parameters
              request.setParameters(params);

              // Execute the request
              Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
                // request.executeAsync();

                }
            }
          }
        });
```